# asp.net Core Add Response Headers in Middleware after UseRouting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, middleware

I'm trying to add a server-side latency header through middleware. I've looked at several SO posts that have similar questions, but their solutions aren't working for me. Here's what I have in my `Startup.cs`

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory factory)
{
    app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
    {
         ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
    });

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });

    app.MyHeaderMiddleware();
}
```

I have to register `MyHeaderMiddleware` after `UseRouting` and `UseEndpoints` because it also needs the endpoint data.

Then in a extension method class, I've got the following.

```cs
public static void MyHeaderMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.MyHeaderMiddleware((context, logger) =>
    {
        var actionDescriptor = endpoint.Metadata.GetMetadata<ControllerActionDescriptor>();
        int status = context.Response.StatusCode;

        if (context.Request.Host != null)
        {
            logger.PutProperty("Host", context.Request.Host.Value);
        }

        if (context.Request?.HttpContext?.Connection?.RemoteIpAddress != null)
        {
            logger.PutProperty("SourceIp", context.Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString());
        }

        if (context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("X-Forwarded-For", out StringValues value) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && value.Count > 0)
        {
            logger.PutProperty("X-Forwarded-For", value.ToArray());
        }
   
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    });
}

public static void MyHeaderMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder app, Func<HttpContext, IMetricsLogger, Task> metricsSetup)
{
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
                
        var logger = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IMetricsLogger>();
        await metricsSetup(context, logger);

        context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
        {
            stopWatch.Stop();
            context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Server-Side-Latency", stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });
                
        await next();
    });
}
```

If I register my middleware before `UseRouting`, the header is added as expected, but if it comes after, it executes, but the header is not seen in the response. I need to setup my metrics logger as part of this because I'm both recording the server-side latency for every API call as well as putting it in the http response.

Comment: There might be something that affect your result, I was surprised that if the response header doesn't appear if it was register after `UseRouting` and made a test myself and it worked as expected (I just copy your code and use class middleware implemented, instead of inline middleware style), could you show how `metricsSetup` was implement ?

Comment: There's a lot of code there, but i'll paste the major parts into the example.

Answer (score 0):

I changed some of the ordering of steps that ended up getting this to work. The major change was this.

```cs
await next(); // this will make the endpoints available in the logger setup
await metricsSetup(context, logger);
```

and to a lesser degree, this:

```cs
app.UseRouting();
app.UseEmfMiddleware();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

By calling `next()` before the metrics logger is setup, the endpoints are made available even though they come after this middleware in the startup.